# How can you share a data table over Snowflake such that the receiver can only left-join onto it, regardless of the name of the file they are using?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to find a way to have partners in other companies be able to left-join any of their Snowflake data tables onto one of mine (let's call it the Big Table), without giving them access to view or copy any other portion of the Big Table.

I've tried writing a UDTF that accesses a view of the Big Table, but the lack of dynamic table querying makes it impractical to share, as ideally the partner can simply input the name + location of the table they'd like to join.

I've tried writing a stored procedure, only to discover that in Snowflake shares can't be granted usage of procedures: `Grant not executed: Operation not supported on a SHARE object.`

It feels like I'm missing something fundamental. How can I share the Big Table securely?

I've included Snowflake SQL code below that demonstrates my attempts:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE FUNCTION UDTF_ATTEMPT()
RETURNS TABLE(
RECORDID STRING,
MATCHKEY VARCHAR(20),
NEW_SECURE_INFO VARCHAR(200)
)
AS 
$$
SELECT C.RECORDID, C.MATCHKEY, BT.NEW_SECURE_INFO
FROM CLIENT_FILE C
LEFT JOIN BIG_TABLE_VIEW BT
ON C.MATCHKEY = BT.MATCHKEY
$$;
// Above: UDTF, but I have to predefine CLIENT_FILE which should be dynamic, OR...//

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_ATTEMPT:
    (
    INPUT_TABLE VARCHAR,
    OUTPUT_TABLE VARCHAR
    )
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    VAR SQLCOMMAND = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE " + OUTPUT_TABLE + " AS SELECT C.RECORDID, C.MATCHKEY, BT.NEW_SECURE_INFO FROM " + INPUT_TABLE + " C LEFT JOIN BIG_TABLE_VIEW BT
ON C.MATCHKEY = BT.MATCHKEY";
    VAR STMT = SNOWFLAKE.CREATESTATEMENT(
        {SQLTEXT: SQLCOMMAND}
        );
    VAR RES = STMT.EXECUTE();
$$;
// Stored Procedure - it's rough, but you get the idea. A copy of the UDTF, with dynamic table querying, but can't be granted usage on a share //
```

Comment: It's not clear, to me, what you are trying to achieve. If you share a view to another account then someone with access to that account can use that view in any query they want to - what are you trying to restrict and why? By definition, a shared view has to be secure so the no-one can see the definition of that view, if that's what you are worried about?

Comment: I'd like to share the ability to left-join onto my Big Table, but not have it so that people can just see the Table / View. My partners should only be allowed to use the sensitive information that is relevant to them.
My understanding is that on a share, you can grant usage of the secure view to the UDTF on a share without granting access to the view. Essentially, the partner can run the UDTF just fine, but can't access the SQL code nor the underlying tables/views that the UDTF calls on. This would be the ideal situation, if the partner could specify which tables they'd like to left-join.

Comment: When you talk about “partners in other companies” do you mean companies that have their own Snowflake accounts and you want to share your data to their accounts, or have you given them access to your Snowflake account? It’s still not clear why you can’t just make the data available to them in a view and instead are trying to build a complex solution using a UDF - which just ends up giving them visibility of exactly the same data they can see in a view which they can then join to their own tables

Comment: By partners, I mean companies that have their own Snowflake accounts that I want to share limited access with.
Perhaps I should clarify that the matchkey could potentially be PII.
If I make the whole data table/view available to them, they could access sensitive information (PII) that they shouldn't have access to, could copy out the Big Table and take our IP, etc. They should only see the rows of the Big Table that is relevant to them, as per our commercial agreement.

Comment: The matchkey potentially being PII is also why my partners couldn't just send their data to me, as me and mine could also be potentially nefarious. We need a method that protects our data both ways.

Comment: So just put the data in a view, secure the view (as explained here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-secure-views.html) or create a view per partner and share the view(s)

Comment: Please correct me if wrong, but to make a secure view as described in the documentation, I would need to know what rows each partner should have access to. This is equivalent to knowing their PII matchkeys, which I don't and shouldn't know. Secondly, a view per partner (per table each partner has) would just be awful to run and update. A single UDTF on a share that I can grant access to would be far easier to run as a user as new partners come in and the needs of old partners change.

Comment: It sounds like what you may want is a data clean room:  https://www.snowflake.com/blog/distributed-data-clean-rooms-powered-by-snowflake/